# "ArgumentError: string contains null byte" when writing Marshalled data into a file

Tags: ruby, json, null, yaml, marshalling

I have a large array, which I want to save to file. But when I issue:

```
File.write Marshal.dump(users),"users.txt"
```

I get:

```
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
from (pry):201:in `write'
```

I get similar results with with JSON and YAML too. What can I do to delete the null bytes from the string? I tried String#scrub but didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the file name and content argument is reversed. The first argument must be the name and the second one the content. The argument error is raised because [file names shouldn't contain null bytes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/10/12/poisoned-NUL-byte-vulnerability/).

And since you're dealing with binary data, you should use  [`IO.binwrite`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-binwrite):

```
File.binwrite "users.txt", Marshal.dump(users)
```

Comment: You might also want to note that `Marshal` isn't a good format for persistence since the `Marshal` format isn't portable to future versions of Ruby.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm looking into using the Marshal format and I'm curious about your statement about it not being portable for future versions. Where can I read more? Do you have an alternative you recommend?

Comment: @Finn Read the [fine Marshal manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Marshal.html). You'd be better off with JSON or YAML files for simple needs, SQLite for more complex self-contained apps, and "real" database of some sort for bigger apps.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Also learned that Marshal is very vulnerable to injection if parsing user data, just like YAML before safe_load. Here is more context: http://tenderlovemaking.com/2013/02/06/yaml-f7u12.html

Did a quick benchmark test and JSON is **A LOT** faster than YAML when it comes to 'dumping' a hash (by a factor of ~30). YAML: 40s, Marshal: 0.9s, JSON: 1.2s (n=100,000)